# I'm getting a Undefined index: columns and a Undefined index: draw error in data tables

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm using the same server side code on two different projects. It works in one, but gives two errors in the other. This is php page

```
/*
 * DataTables example server-side processing script.
 *
 * Please note that this script is intentionally extremely simply to show how
 * server-side processing can be implemented, and probably shouldn't be used as
 * the basis for a large complex system. It is suitable for simple use cases as
 * for learning.
 *
 * See http://datatables.net/usage/server-side for full details on the server-
 * side processing requirements of DataTables.
 *
 * @license MIT - http://datatables.net/license_mit
 */

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* Easy set variables
*/

// DB table to use
$table = 'salef';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'Parcel';


// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'Parcel',     'dt' => 'Parcel' ),
array( 'db' => 'StreetNumber',     'dt' => 'StreetNumber' ),
array( 'db' => 'StreetName',     'dt' => 'StreetName' ),
array( 'db' => 'StreetType',     'dt' => 'StreetType' ),
array( 'db' => 'StreetDirection',     'dt' => 'StreetDirection' ),
array( 'db' => 'school',     'dt' => 'school' ),
array( 'db' => 'twp',     'dt' => 'twp' ),
array( 'db' => 'corp',     'dt' => 'corp' ),
array( 'db' => 'SaleNumber',     'dt' => 'SaleNumber' ),
array( 'db' => 'SaleMonth',     'dt' => 'SaleMonth' ),
array( 'db' => 'SaleYear',     'dt' => 'SaleYear' ),
array( 'db' => 'SalePrice',     'dt' => 'SalePrice' ),
array( 'db' => 'LivingArea',     'dt' => 'LivingArea' ),
array( 'db' => 'Acres',     'dt' => 'Acres' ),
array( 'db' => 'YearBuilt',     'dt' => 'YearBuilt' ),
array( 'db' => 'Story',     'dt' => 'Story' ),
array( 'db' => 'Plus',     'dt' => 'Plus' ),
array( 'db' => 'Basement',     'dt' => 'Basement' ),
array( 'db' => 'Qtr',     'dt' => 'Qtr' ),
array( 'db' => 'Frame',     'dt' => 'Frame' ),
array( 'db' => 'Bedrooms',     'dt' => 'Bedrooms' ),
array( 'db' => 'BasementSqft',     'dt' => 'BasementSqft' ),
array( 'db' => 'FinishedBasment',     'dt' => 'FinishedBasment' ),
array( 'db' => 'AirCond',     'dt' => 'AirCond' ),
array( 'db' => 'GarageSqft',     'dt' => 'GarageSqft' ),
array( 'db' => 'GarageCode',     'dt' => 'GarageCode' ),
array( 'db' => 'AirCode',     'dt' => 'AirCode' ),
array( 'db' => 'Roof',     'dt' => 'Roof' ),
array( 'db' => 'RoofType',     'dt' => 'RoofType' ),
array( 'db' => 'Rooms',     'dt' => 'Rooms' ),
array( 'db' => 'FullBaths',     'dt' => 'FullBaths' ),
array( 'db' => 'HalfBaths',     'dt' => 'HalfBaths' ),
array( 'db' => 'Grade',     'dt' => 'Grade' ),
array( 'db' => 'MHRE',     'dt' => 'MHRE' ),
array( 'db' => 'NeighCode',     'dt' => 'NeighCode' ),
array( 'db' => 'PropClass',     'dt' => 'PropClass' ),
array( 'db' => 'LandValue',     'dt' => 'LandValue' ),
array( 'db' => 'BldgValue',     'dt' => 'BldgValue' ),
array( 'db' => 'parcelUrl',     'dt' => 'parcelUrl' ),
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
'user' => 'root',
'pass' => 'sql2002',
'db'   => 'mysql',
'host' => 'localhost'
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( '../js/DataTables-1.10.5/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns)
);
//echo '<pre>';
//echo print_r($_POST);
//
//echo print_r($sql_details);
//echo print_r($table);
//echo print_r($primaryKey);
//echo print_r($columns);
//
//echo '</pre>';
```

This is all on its own php page, so when I call that php page I get this,

```
Notice: Undefined index: columns in /www/websvr6/htdocs/re/js/DataTables-1.10.5/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php on line 177

Notice: Undefined index: draw in /www/websvr6/htdocs/re/js/DataTables-1.10.5/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php on line 263
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":5342,"recordsFiltered":5342,"data":[{"Parcel":"010035000000","StreetNumber":"","StreetName":"STATE HWY 29","StreetType":"","StreetDirection":"","school":"2D","twp":"4A","corp":"","SaleNumber":" 364","SaleMonth":" 8","SaleYear":"06","SalePrice":" 128000","LivingArea":"","Acres":" 5600","YearBuilt":"","Story":"","Plus":"","Basement":"","Qtr":"","Frame":"","Bedrooms":"","BasementSqft":"","FinishedBasment":"","AirCond":"","GarageSqft":"","GarageCode":"","AirCode":"","Roof":"","RoofType":"","Rooms":"","FullBaths":"","HalfBaths":"","Grade":"","MHRE":"","NeighCode":" 102","PropClass":"501","LandValue":" 2030","BldgValue":"","parcelUrl":"http:\/\/www.co.wyandot.oh.us\/cards\/Curnt\/010035000000.pdf"},
```

And this goes on for about 5k records. I'm using version 1.10.5. And can't figure out what the deal is. This is identical, except for the table name and the columns, to what I'm doing on another page but on this page it doesn't work. If I try to call this from the main page with ajax I get an error also, which is why I decided to call the php page to see what I got. The biggest thing I noticed is that on this output I'm getting this at the beginning of my output

```
draw":0,"recordsTotal":5342,"recordsFiltered":5342,
```

On my other page, I just get the table data.

Comment: Can you post the code of the two pages. Thanks

Comment: The error means that the browser doesn't send proper server-side request (absence of `columns` and `draw` parameters). Most likely your JavaScript initialization code is different, for example you didn't specify `serverSide:true` with the second table.

Comment: Right, but if I bypass the JavaScript and only use php I should get results like I am but without errors. The results I'm getting above are without the use of any JavaScript.

Comment: I had to call this using javascript and using $_POST because the data base is so big. It works fine.